# Die Rolling Game from Visual Logic

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Visual Logic flowchart to write a python program. I just cant get it to work. What is wrong? Please help! I'm sorry I'm such a newbie and just don't get it.
Here's what I have so far:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Programmer:   Les
# Program name: Program to define an array
# Date written: November 08, 2013
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Introduction lines
print("-"*50 + "\n");
print(("Final Project ---> Rolling a Die") + "\n");
print(("Written by Les") + "\n");
print("-"*50 + "\n");
print(" \n");

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Define first array
firstCounters = 1 * 6

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Input for first round
firstRollsToMake = int(input("Please enter how many times the die should be rolled in the first round ---> \n "));
print(" \n");

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Make die
import random

def dice(sides=6):
    return random.randint(1,sides)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rolling the die
for firstRoll in range(1, firstRollsToMake, 1):

    dieValue = float(random.randint(min,max));
    firstCounters[dieValue] = (firstCounters[dieValue] + 1);
# End for loop

print();
print("-"*50 + "\n");
print(" \n");

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Display the percentages
print(format("The value ") + format(firstRollStats) + format(" was rolled ") + format(firstCounters(firstRollStats)) + format(" times") + format(" \n"));
diePercentageOne = (firstCounters(firstRollStats))/firstRollsToMake
print(format(" or ") + format(FormatPercent(diePercentageOne)) + format(" \n"));

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Display histogram results
print(format("Below are the results in histogram form\n"));
for histogram in range(1, 6, 1):
    print(format(histogram) + (" : "));
    for circleLoop in range(1, firstCounters[histogram], 1):
        print(format("0"));
    print(format(" \n"));
print(format(" \n"));

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Define second array

secondCounters = 1 * 6

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Input for second round
secondRollsToMake = int(input("Please enter how many times the die should be rolled in the second round ---> \n "));
print(" \n");

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rolling the die again
for secondRoll in range(1, secondRollsToMake, 1):

    dieValueTwo = float(random.randint(min,max));
    secondCounters[dieValueTwo] = (secondCounters[dieValueTwo] + 1);
# End for loop

print();
print("-"*50 + "\n");
print(" \n");

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Display the second percentages
print(format("The value ") + format(secondRollStats) + format(" was rolled ") + format(secondCounters(secondRollStats)) + format(" times") + format(" \n"));
diePercentageTwo = (secondCounters(secondRollStats))/secondRollsToMake
print(format(" or ") + format(FormatPercent(diePercentageTwo)) + format(" \n"));

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Display second histogram results
print(format("Below are the results in histogram form\n"));
for histogramTwo in range(1, 6, 1):
    print(format(histogramTwo) + (" : "));
    for circleLoop in range(1, secondCounters[histogramTwo], 1):
        print(format("0"));
    print(format(" \n"));
print(format(" \n"));

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Number of times rolled comment
print(format("Comment on the number of times rolled:\n"));
print(format("\n"));
while (firstRollsToMake == secondRollsToMake):
    if (firstRollsToMake == secondRollsToMake):
        print(format("Since the die was rolled the same amount of times in both rounds, the results are not skewed and can be compared and contrasted fairly\n"));
    elif (firstRollsToMake < secondRollsToMake):
        print(format("Since the die was rolled fewer times in the first round than the second, the results are skewed and cannot be compared and contrasted fairly\n"));
    else:
        print(format("Since the die was rolled more times in the first round than the second, the results are skewed and cannot be compared and contrasted fairly\n"));

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# End program
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work?  What output do you expect to see, and what do you actually get?  Moreover, what's a "Visual Logic flowchart"?  Is it relevant to the code?  If so, the flowchart should probably be included in the question.  If not, why bring it up?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `dieValue = float(random.randint(min,max));`  `min` and `max` are the names of Python functions and are not variables in your program.

Comment: As a general note, pasting a long program into a question and saying "I just can't get it to work" is usually not a great idea: people are much more likely to respond positively if you provide a short snippet that demonstrates a problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: `for firstRoll in range(1, firstRollsToMake, 1)`: I think you mean `for firstRoll in range(firstRollsToMake)`, if you start from 1 you'll get one less roll than needed. The step of 1 is implied so can be omitted.

Comment: "Final Project"? How can a teacher assign the same final project to a plethora of people? You are now like the sixth person in two days, asking exactely the same...

Comment: When is this assignment due and how many are there in your course?

Answer (score 2):

I already answered two friends of yours with the same assignment:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    dice = int(input("Enter the number of dice: "))
    sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides: "))
    rolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls to simulate: "))
    result = roll(dice, sides, rolls)
    maxH = 0
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        if result[i] / rolls > maxH: maxH = result[i] / rolls
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        print('{:2d}{:10d}{:8.2%} {}'.format(i, result[i], result[i] / rolls, '#' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 40)))


def roll(dice, sides, rolls):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.randint(1, sides) for _ in range(dice))] += 1
    return d

main()
```

You can take out the parts which are useful to you. This should also cover the follow-up questions like: "How do I print it neatly" and "How do I draw a histogram".

Example:

```
Enter the number of dice: 2
Enter the number of sides: 6
Enter the number of rolls to simulate: 1000
 2        28   2.80% ######
 3        59   5.90% #############
 4        84   8.40% ###################
 5        96   9.60% ######################
 6       155  15.50% ####################################
 7       170  17.00% ########################################
 8       147  14.70% ##################################
 9       102  10.20% #######################
10        80   8.00% ##################
11        50   5.00% ###########
12        29   2.90% ######
```

Comment: Like it. However, you can factor `rolls` out of your `maxH` calculations and make it much simpler. Maybe even `maxH = max(result.values())` instead of the first loop

Comment: @cmd Very true. This histogram was a quick-n-dirty addendum to the original code. Thanks for your input, but nevertheless I will leave it the same, so that OP and his class mates all have the same solution.